# Update favicon via link in text box and button

Tags: javascript, html

Sorta like
when you click the button, you get the favicon.ico from the link (using js)
an example ico would be [stackoverflow favicon](Https://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico)

```js
  //this is the js section
//some way to read the text box and Retrieve favicon from link
```

```html
<button Id=button Onclick=<!--add Update favicon function here -->
Favicon.ico</button>
<input type=box id=field text="input Text here">
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, this should work:

```
function updateFavicon(link){
  let exists = $("link[rel*='icon']");
  if(exists.length){
    $("link[rel*='icon']").attr('href', link);
  } else {
    $("head").append("<link rel='icon' href='" + link + "'>");
  }
}
```

And then:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="link">
  <button onclick="updateFavicon($('#link').val())">Update Favicon</button>
</div>
```

Comment: does not seen to work, link is [here](https://gameninja-matsu.000webhostapp.com/test.html)

Comment: You need to include jQuery to make it work.

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: the console caught an error stat ing that `Uncaught ReferenceError: updateFavicon is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (test.html:13)
onclick @ test.html:13`

Comment: still doesnt work

Comment: Ok, wait a minute

Comment: Ok, it should work now. https://tricksfortheweb.com/stack/favicon.html. See updated answer.